# Airflow scheduler refuses to launch on demon mode

Tags: airflow

When I run `airflow scheduler` eveything works (Airflow 1.9.0)

But if I want to run using `airflow scheduler -D` nothing works. The scheduler does not launch.

When I do: `ps aux | grep 'airflow'` after I run `airflow scheduler -D` I see:
[image]

Why the scheduler doesn't start?

**Edit:**
I see this error in `airflow-scheduler.err` file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 817, in scheduler
    with ctx:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 397, in __enter__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 389, in open
    self.pidfile.__enter__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lockfile/__init__.py", line 197, in __enter__
    self.acquire()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daemon/pidfile.py", line 60, in acquire
    super(TimeoutPIDLockFile, self).acquire(timeout, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lockfile/pidlockfile.py", line 88, in acquire
    self.path)
lockfile.AlreadyLocked: /home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow-scheduler.pid is already locked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in `airflow-scheduler.err` or `airflow-scheduler.out` - that is where stderr and stdout are redirected to by default.

From the error you mentioned ("lockfile.AlreadyLocked: /home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow-scheduler.pid is already locked") the problem is that previously the scheduler exited without tidying up it's lockfile. The short term fix is to remove the mentioned PID file.

Next time it crashes check the .err file - it might mention why it's crashed. Another thing to check is does the crash time line up with you logging out of an SSH session? If so then [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) might help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last row you wrote. I want it to run without occupying my console.. simply run in the background. When I do:  `airflow scheduler -D 2> error.log`  I see same warning as seen in the screen shoot. I don't see any error.

Comment: Run with the flags suggested. -D will likely close stdout and stderr otherwise, meaning you don't get further output.

Comment: This is the what log shows: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/init.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)   same as console.

Comment: check the new image in question

Comment: I just checked the code, and I was slightly wrong - if you don't specify those options then by default you will get airflow-scheduler.err, airflow-scheduler.out and airflow-scheduler.log files. Is there anything useful in any of those?

Comment: airflow-scheduler.err shows:
lockfile.AlreadyLocked: /home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow-scheduler.pid is already locked